# How do I check for PROGRAM idle time, as opposed to SYSTEM idle time?

Tags: delphi

I have a program that occasionally needs to scan some directories recursively (an improvement for this part of the program is in the pipeline, but won't be ready for a while). To avoid the user having to wait for this scanning, I would like to do the scanning while the user isn't using my program when possible.

I intend to implement it by running a timer that checks for idle time. I've found the following for checking system idle time:
http://www.delphitips.net/2007/11/11/how-to-detect-system-idle-time/

This would be functional, but I would prefer to activate the function even when the user is working with other programs on the same computer. This way, if he switches to another program, I could catch up on the scanning I need to do.

I realize that I could do the scanning in a background thread, and either that or some sort of windows hooks will be implemented at some point, but not just yet.

EDIT:
The goal here is a relatively easy change to the program to do any scanning that might be queued while the user isn't actively using MY application. The scanning isn't especially intensive, but it isn't done in a thread, and therefore freezes my app while in progress. Basically, I'm looking for a quick win while I'm working on a more long term solution.

Comment: A Thread would not care if the App was Idle and would not prevent them from using the application?

Comment: Could you not use the OnIdle call in TApplication? You could increment a counter for each call to OnIdle and reset it every 1s. If it climbs to an 'amount' you go do your stuff.

Comment: He *could* use OnIdle, @Brian, but not in the way you've suggested. That's not how the event works.

Comment: Start right off by putting it in a background thread.  It'll be *simpler* to implement than responding to events.  Also, what are you scanning for?  There's several win api funcs that will alert you to a change in a directory that may make your scanning much simpler to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`Application.OnIdle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnIdle) event. That event is triggered when your program has no more window messages to handle. The keyboard and mouse both generate messages, so if there are no more messages, then the user is not using your program, even if it has the focus.

```
procedure TJasonForm.ApplicationEventsIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
var
  NoMoreFiles: Boolean;
begin
  // TODO: Scan for the next file
  Done := NoMoreFiles;
end;
```

As long as `Done` is False and there are no messages in the queue, your program will continue to call that event handler, allowing you to find more files. When the user generates some input, your program will handle the messages before calling `OnIdle` again.

When you've finished scanning the file system, set `Done` to True so that the program stops re-calling the `OnIdle` handler. If you neglect to do that, then your program will use all available CPU time repeatedly calling an event handler that does nothing.

For this to work, you'll need to use a *non-recursive* search routine. A recursive search will search the whole file system before returning, but if you do that, then the `OnIdle` handler will hang your program, which is the oposite of what you want. You can use a queue of directory names, and each time the event is fires, pop one item off the queue, search it, and add its contents to the end of the queue.

Comment: Remember that even just moving your mouse pointer within your application's window will send window messages to your application for it to handle. The user isn't _using_ your application as such. You might want to take this into consideration.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I only have limited scope for breaking up my search. This would be ideal, if I could add some kind of wait. Perhaps I could activate a timer from the OnIdle function? Then it would be more likely that the user actually is idle, and didn't just stop moving the mouse momentarily.

Comment: Where the timer would of course check that the program is still idle, and then start the scanning.

Comment: Yes, you could probably do that. Set the state to "idle" when you get an OnIdle event; set it to "not idle" when you get an OnMessage event.

Comment: And if I want to scan again after a while how can I receive OnIdle if I set Done to true ?

Answer (score 2):

> ...but I would prefer to activate the
>   function even when the user is working
>   with other programs on the same
>   computer. This way, if he switches to
>   another program, I could catch up on
>   the scanning I need to do.

Stop the scanning in Application.OnActivate and resume in Application.OnDeactivate.

Comment: This is also useful. If I combined this with my version of Rob's solution, I could pretty efficiently start scanning whenever the user switches away from my application or is idle while using my application.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a separate thread that will be resumed when the system is idle or paused when there is activity. A simple way to do this is to place a Timer Component and check if the system is idle and thread is suspended or not use ResumeThread ,SuspendThread

Look here

http://pastebin.com/8X9Sg42H i crafted something for your situation enjoy

Comment: If it's a separate thread, set its priority to "idle" and let the OS take care of scheduling it automatically.

Comment: A low priority thread that is using I/O can hold up a higher priority thread if once the I/O is begun, the higher priority thread has to wait for the I/O to complete before continuing. This is quite likely to happen if the low priority thread is scanning files.

Comment: Do not use suspend/resume to control thread execution, just don't, it's too dangerous. Do it properly.  Create a thread at app startup. Do not terminate it or use TThread.waitFor/Synchronize/OnTerminate, just loop around a 'ReadDirectoryChangesW'call, stuff results into a TstringList instance and PostMessage it to a control/form.  Try very hard not to use a timer/onIdle bodge. By all means set the priority lower, as Rob suggested.

Comment: I had never had any problems using suspend and resume thread but you might be right if the thread performs complex operations

Comment: Thanks for the code/comments. When I replace the current scanning code, it's likely that I will do the scanning in a background thread, but this will require significant changes to the code. Right now I'm looking for a quick win to make the slow code that I inherited *seem* faster.

Comment: @userR3TarD It's just an example

Comment: @MartinJames Not sure why you think Suspend/Resume is too dangerous. You have to consider that suspend could happen _at any time_, so obviously if the thread obtains any kind of lock shared by another thread then your application will deadlock, but apart from this what is the danger?